Apache subdomain on local server
I'm not able to create working subdomain in Apache. Before posting here, I searched internet, read plenty of similar questions on stack sites, asked chatgpt, read Apache documentation and tried various different configurations. (And ofc. I restart httpd every time :)
But I'm stuck. I'd say I'm fairly experienced in Linux, but beginner in Apache. Also, many online resources are written from Debian based perspective which differs considerably from RedHat.
My environment
I'm using Manjaro as my host OS. There I have Rocky9 minimal with httpd, running in Virtual box. It is a fresh install, so there are no misconfiguration from past.
What I want to achieve
I want to access two different webpages from my host machine.

idd.ph should show /var/www/html/index.html
example.idd.ph should show /var/www/example/index.html

However, I always get the same index.html for both subdomains.

idd.ph returns /var/www/example/index.html
example.idd.ph also returns /var/www/example/index.html

If I switch order of my VirtualHosts, I will get /var/www/html/index.html for both subdomains.
My setup
idd.ph is an arbitrary domain and it is set in /etc/hosts on my Manjaro host:
192.168.0.109 idd.ph
192.168.0.109 example.idd.ph

On Rocky I created a file normal.conf inside /etc/httpd/conf.d
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

This is the structure of /var/www or Rocky:
.
├── cgi-bin
├── example
│   └── index.html
└── html
    └── index.html

I also edited /etc/hosts on Rocky like this:
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.0.1   example.localhost

Thank you in advance.

Servername should match the hostname

Thank you, that was it!
But I wonder, is there a (correct) way how to set it up, so it recognizes subdomain, even if the domain doesn't match? Like, if I would change my local /etc/hosts entry, I will break it again.

Added ad answer, also mention the problem in comment.

As you have in hosts file this:
192.168.0.109 idd.ph
192.168.0.109 example.idd.ph

you should add in apache config this:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.idd.ph
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName idd.ph
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

The host names in apache should match DNS resolved names.
If you change hosts you will break local resolve (can't see the http hosts from the same machine). And if you have external name source (as DNS) the rest of the machines will access the apache.
